Throwing ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ORB error while accessing html response in Ionic Capacitor
Context
We have a Content Player where we are loading online contents(html, js pdf audio, video). It was working perfectly untill few month back.
Issue
Now we are unable to access html contents where it has some custom html tags.
<div ng-show="customNavigationVisible" ng-controller="CustomNavigationCtrl">
    <custom-next-navigation></custom-next-navigation>
    <custom-previous-navigation></custom-previous-navigation>
</div>

In the network tab it is throwing (failed)net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ORB error.
Things
Sample Repo
https://github.com/vinukumar-vs/ionic-content-player-proxy/tree/main
We have tried adding proxy for that specific url which didn't work
Seems in the new chrome version is causing this issue.
How can we fix this issue ?
